# Binding error when changing the property to dependency object

Tags: c#, wpf, bind

i am using the below codes to use a system of class in my control:

```
public class FlowProWorkingClass:DependencyObject
{
    public TUnitSystemClass ProjectUnitSystem
    {
        get
        {
            return Classes.CurrentFlowProWorkingClass.GeneralOptions.listOfUnitSystems.Find(x => x.Id == Classes.CurrentFlowProWorkingClass.GeneralOptions.DefaultUnitSystemId);
        }
        set
        {
            throw new Exception("Project Unit System can not be setted here!");}
        }
}
```

and i have bind it to the my control as below:

```
<WPFTextBoxUnitConverterControl:TextBoxUnitConvertor
    x:Name="txtGasPhaseFlowCoefficient" UnitSystem="{Binding currentFlowProWorkingClass.ProjectUnitSystem, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource CurrentFlowProWorkingClass}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Height="27" Margin="167,245,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="171"/>
```

this code is working good and get the system of units currently.
now need the control , when it is opens, so that i revised the first class to add the below code to notify on change:

```
public class FlowProWorkingClass:DependencyObject
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProjectUnitSystemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ProjectUnitSystem",
            typeof(TUnitSystemClass),
            typeof(FlowProWorkingClass),
            new PropertyMetadata(ProjectUnitSystemOnChanged));

    private static void ProjectUnitSystemOnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public TUnitSystemClass ProjectUnitSystem
    {
        get
        {
            SetValue(ProjectUnitSystemProperty, Classes.CurrentFlowProWorkingClass.GeneralOptions.listOfUnitSystems.Find(x => x.Id == Classes.CurrentFlowProWorkingClass.GeneralOptions.DefaultUnitSystemId));
            return (TUnitSystemClass) GetValue(ProjectUnitSystemProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            throw new Exception("Project Unit System can not be setted here!");
        }
    }
}
```

but now, the control is not binded at all!
whats the problem?
NOTE: when i wrote the below code, the binding is ignored fully! the get method is not called at all! why?

```
public static DependencyProperty ProjectUnitSystemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ProjectUnitSystem",
        typeof(TUnitSystemClass),
        typeof(FlowProWorkingClass),
        new PropertyMetadata(ProjectUnitSystemOnChanged));

private static void ProjectUnitSystemOnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
}

public TUnitSystemClass ProjectUnitSystem
{
    get
    {
        SetValue(ProjectUnitSystemProperty, Classes.CurrentFlowProWorkingClass.GeneralOptions.listOfUnitSystems.Find(x => x.Id == Classes.CurrentFlowProWorkingClass.GeneralOptions.DefaultUnitSystemId));
        return (TUnitSystemClass) GetValue(ProjectUnitSystemProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        throw new Exception("Project Unit System can not be setted here!");
    }
}
```

Comment: i revised it, but the they are not showing correctly! plz some one edit it as i can not do that!

Comment: Throwing exeptions from propery setter makes no sense at all. Make the properties readonly.

Comment: @clemens - the property must be setted from another way in another property which is getted in get!"Classes.CurrentFlowProWorkingClass.GeneralOptions.listOfUnitSystems"

Comment: That makes no sense. A property setter that throws an exception should just not be there. As a note, we say get and set also in past tense, not getted and setted.

Comment: As another note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on a one-way Binding has no effect. You should remove it. As a general rule, never set it unless you actually need it.

Comment: @clemens - thanks. you are absolutly right

Comment: @clemens - generally i can explain my problem as follows, consider three propert named a , b and c where c is bound to b! b does not have any value and it returns the value of a. now i need c to be changed when the a changes! how can i do that?

Comment: Bind b to a - b would have to be read/write. If b must be readonly, make the class that owns it implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and raise the PropertyChanged event for b when a changes.

Comment: @clemens - can you provide me a breif code?(note that b is a property is another class!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137740/discussion-between-all-and-clemens).

Answer (score 1):

`SetValue` sets a so-called local value of a dependency property, which replaces any previously assigned (one-way) Binding.

So your property getter effectively removes the Binding. It must not call `SetValue`.

```
get
{
    SetValue(ProjectUnitSystemProperty, ...); // remove this line
    return (TUnitSystemClass)GetValue(ProjectUnitSystemProperty);
}
```

The CLR wrapper of any read/write dependency property must look exactly like this:

```
public PropertyType PropertyName
{
    get { return (PropertyType)GetValue(PropertyNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PropertyNameProperty, value); 
}
```

For read-only dependency properties take a look at the [Read-Only Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754044(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: unfortunately the get must first get the value from another property "Classes.CurrentFlowProWorkingClass.GeneralOptions.listOfUnitSystems.Find(x => x.Id == Classes.CurrentFlowProWorkingClass.GeneralOptions.DefaultUnitSystemId) " and then return it! !

Comment: Dependency properties don't work that way. You have to call SetValue *before* the getter is called, not inside the getter.

Comment: i need the get return the real time value of  the property "Classes.CurrentFlowProWorkingClass.GeneralOptions.listOfUni‌​tSystems.Find(x => x.Id == Classes.CurrentFlowProWorkingClass.GeneralOptions.DefaultUni‌​tSystemId)"! can i do that?

Comment: Don't make ProjectUnitSystem a dependency property.

Comment: I need it to be notified on change to change all of the controls that are bound to it

Comment: That contradicts with your apparent requirement that it should be readonly. So how should it be changed (externally).

Comment: see the revision that i have made please!